# How do you extend the time required to trigger hot corner actions?

Tags: macos, ui

I like the concept of hot corner actions but the trigger time for hot corner actions is too quick for me to make good use of them. I keep tripping my corner actions accidentally while reaching for objects in that general vicinity of the corner.

Is it possible to extend the trigger time for hot corner actions? So I have to hover in the corner for at least a second or two before the hot corner action triggers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not know how do delay the triggering, but you can **add modifier keys** to the hot corners in order to avoid accidental activation:

Hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>,<kbd>⌥</kbd>,<kbd>⇧</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while selecting an option from the list.[image]

Comment: Curse you gentmatt! I was just writing the same answer! :( (Related: SE's "new answer posted" notice is really helpful. I ultimately didn't waste the time on an answer someone else already gave.)

Comment: Haha! There will be more races for the first answer in the future... :)

Comment: Not intuitive or discoverable at all. Also if I wanted to use the keyboard, I'd just use a keyboard combo for locking. Still looking for a way to configure a delay. Maybe we can swap out the locker?

Answer (score 15):

a bit late, but I guess relevant...

I was stuck with the same issue of adding a **delay**, NOT a modifier key.

Well, there's a workaround.

In the corner you want to use as a lock after a short delay, put **Start Screen Saver** in the Hot Corners dialogue, instead of **Lock Screen**. Then go to Security & Privacy and under General, set 5 seconds delay in **Require Password after...**

And you're done!

Comment: Thanks!  I know this is beside the point...but I just needed to vent that unfortunately 5 seconds is not small enough.  I just want to prevent the accidental activation of the hot corner (like 1 second needed...maybe 2 max).  Now, I have to wait 5 seconds to make sure my screen saver stays on before walking away so someone doesn't "accidentally" bump my mouse and have access to my machine.

Comment: @jbobbins you can set it as `immediately`

Comment: @Charlestone immediately does not give me any buffer whatsoever to make a "mistake".  If I accidentally move the mouse down to a hot corner (which happens fairly often), I don't want it immediately activating.  I need a second, maybe two, of buffer time (but not 5 seconds for reasons I explained).

Comment: The hot corner does not immediately activate - it takes like 1-2 seconds. The "immediate" lock screen is after screensaver is activated after 1-2s after hot corner ;) just try it! :D

Comment: I can confirm that this creates a desirable behavior!