# Any way to set a delay before activation on hot corners?

Tags: mac, settings, screen-lock

Edit: Found a good workaround here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354755/359900

There is a few post on this, but mostly many years old. Is there any way to add a delay on hot corners to avoid accidental activation?

Adding a key is possible, but then the advantage over using the default key combination is quite small.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which post/key are your referring to?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436221/hot-corners-in-monterey-are-too-hot-very-easily-triggered and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40238/how-do-you-extend-the-time-required-to-trigger-hot-corner-actions

Comment: Found this on one of then which is a great workaround "In the corner you want to use as a lock after a short delay, put Start Screen Saver in the Hot Corners dialogue, instead of Lock Screen. Then go to Security & Privacy and under General, set 5 seconds delay in Require Password after..."